# Nicol prism as analyzer

Tags: optics, waves, polarization, intensity

I recently read in my notes when circularly polarized ray are passed through Nicol prism then there is no variation in intensity.

But When it is first passed through nicol prism ordinary ray will undergo TIR and there should be change in the intensity.

There is contradiction in what I read and what I am thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't read it properly
It's trying to convey you that after TIR variation of intesity was seen because of polarization due to reflection.